# XSLT : Value-of select using date attribute

Tags: xslt

Currently I am trying to pull data from csv using the value-of select command in xslt. I am totally new to xslt and while to trying to read the values, I am able to do so for string attribute but for date and number attribute i am not able to. Please find below my current code and the related output. Could someone help me how to read the date/number field from csv.
Code:

```
<cas:label>HR data</cas:label>          
            <cas:property>
                    <cas:key>CustomerId</cas:key>
                    <cas:value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="a/string[position()=1]"/>
                    </cas:value>
                </cas:property>
                <cas:property>
                    <cas:key>ReportingPeriod</cas:key>
                    <cas:value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="a/string[position()=4]"/>
                    </cas:value>
                </cas:property>
                <cas:property>
                    <cas:key>LeaseCarStartDate</cas:key>
                    <cas:value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="a/date[position()=5]"/>
                    </cas:value>
                </cas:property>
```

Output as below:

```
<cas:label>HR data</cas:label>
      <cas:property>
         <cas:key>CustomerId</cas:key>
         <cas:value>RD2</cas:value>
      </cas:property>
<cas:property>
         <cas:key>ReportingPeriod</cas:key>
         <cas:value>12-2016</cas:value>
      </cas:property>
<cas:property>
         <cas:key>LeaseCarStartDate</cas:key>
         <cas:value/>
      </cas:property>
```

Comment: Please post your XSLT.

Comment: XSLT requires an XML document as input, not a CSV file. If your CSV data is actually embedded in an XML document, it would probably help if you showed your input XML. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the input data.

It doesn't look like CSV to me.

Note however that

```
select=a/date[position()=5]
```

selects the fifth date element, and I suspect from your question that there is only one.